# Use HTML documents like stylesheets

Tags: html

i'm making a website for someone who is not particularly well acquainted with html and i want them to be able to edit the content of their webpage just from a blank text/html file (or easier method),
i'm wondering if there is anyway i can just have a text document but save it as a html which i could load within `<p></p>` tags

for example: maindocument.html

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="text">....[someway of getting text from textdocument.html (or .txt)]....</p>
</body>
</html>
```

textdocument.html (or.txt)

```
"text to go within p tags"
```

you can do this with css style sheets and scripts so is there a way to do this with basic html?

Comment: SSI includes possible?

Comment: is there a reason why he/she is not going with wordpress or tumblr?

Comment: I've suggested it to them but they feel its "too bloggy" i think they want it to revolve around videos and images rather than text

Comment: @clairharrison: Make a demo and then suggest it. This is going to be *painful* to work with.

Comment: @clairharrison: If their content is expected to mostly consist of videos and images, Tumblr sounds like a much better fit for them than a bunch of (semi)static HTML.

Comment: Any answer (including SSI, PHP, etc.) involving directly injecting this text into the body of a `<p>` tag is going to have a problem: all of it will be one paragraph, newlines won't be preserved.

Answer (score 2):

If the web server is running Apache you could use SSI. The files will need to be in .shtm or .shtml format.

Then all you do is

```
<p>
    <!--#include virtual="paragraphs.txt" -->
</p>
```

I'd usually just use PHP includes though.

Answer (score 0):

If a .txt file is enough, I guess you could use an iframe to load it:

```
<iframe src="myfile.txt"></iframe>
```

But if you want rich editing, I'd suggest implementing a WYSIWYG editor and saving it somehow.

Comment: this definately is the right kind of thing im looking for, i could do without it being in a frame of its own though

Comment: You can style the frame so it doesn't look awkward, but implementing a text file without PHP/.NET won't be easy otherwise. You could always use PHP's `<?php include('filename.txt'); ?>` just for this cause and never use it again.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use server-side includes if they are available on your server: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html

Otherwise you might consider using a scripting language like PHP and include the file, like:

```
<?php include("textdocument.html"); ?>
```

Comment: i think ill have a read up on this :) im trying to avoid learning PHP myself but it looks like its going to have to happen